# postgresql golang create table error, pq: syntax error at or near "$1"

Tags: go, psql

Hi I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

```
_, err = db.Exec("CREATE TABLE $1", "books")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

I'm failing to see what is syntactically wrong here.

I have also done:

```
_, err = db.Exec("CREATE TABLE books")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Gives the syntax error as well

Answer (score 4):

Identifiers cannot be used as placeholders. Only values can be used there. (it's not a Go or its db drivers limitations, it's relational databases themselves that have such a "limitation").

In case of hardcoded identifiers - use the exact query

```
CREATE TABLE books
```

In case of dynamic placeholders - ensure you're using white lists of what values are allowed there.

**UPD**

Just this query

```
CREATE TABLE books
```

<strike>is invalid because it's missing any column definitions. It must be at least one column in a table.</strike>

is invalid because it's missing parentheses:

```
CREATE TABLE books()
```

in which you define columns.

TIL: you can have a table with zero columns in postgresql.

References:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html

Comment: I still get an error saying pq: syntax error at end of input

Comment: @ShaunChua please update code in the original question if you need help with it (don't replace though but add a second version with the corresponding error message).

Comment: hi thanks for the solution. If I wanted to create a table with columns do I do this as such: CREATE TABLE books(a,b,c,d)? How do I specify the type of the column? Sorry I'm failing to understand the documentation

Comment: @ShaunChua it would be `<column name> <column type>`, comma separated.